# Copying code to LaTeX without losing the formatting

Tags: code

I have some code of around 350 lines, and I need to paste it inside a LaTeX file without losing the formatting such as the extra spaces. What do I need to use to get this in LaTeX?

Comment: What "code" exactly do you have? Is it some source code that you want to show as a listing (use `verbatim` then)? Could you copy-paste a few lines here as an example?

Comment: Have a look at the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. You can include an external file with `\lstinputlisting`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package `\usepackage{listings}` and put your code in the following way

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
```

For information, you can read the wikibook LaTeX/Source Code Listings at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings